# Taurus : Using an external properties file instead of specifying in YAML

Tags: jmeter, yaml, performance-testing, taurus

In Taurus is it possible to use an external properties file for specifying properties ?

I have read [this](http://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#JMeter-Properties-and-Variables) but didn't find the solution.

My concern is that I have something like 40 properties in existing user.properties and don't want to move them in YAML file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Directly no, however you can define the properties in a separate YAML or JSON file and [include it](https://gettaurus.org/docs/ConfigSyntax/#Included-Configs) into main YAML config like:

```
included-configs:  
- properties.yml  # the file containing your properties definitions
```

Comment: Thank you, is there a plan to allow this ?